# Números primos en matriz

Tags: c, algoritmos, matrices

Enunciado del problema:

> Dada una Matriz de N filas y M columnas que contiene números enteros,
>   escribir una función que devuelva un valor lógico indicando si existe,
>   al menos, un número primo de dicha matriz. En caso de que exista, la
>   función también devolverá en qué posición (fila y colulmna) se
>   encuentra el primer número primo encontrado. En caso de que no exista
>   ningún número primo en la matriz, la función devolverá (-1,-1) como
>   posición.

Mi código ACTUALIZADO en C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 2
#define M 3

int main()
{

    int matriz1[N][M]= {{1,2,1},{3,1,2}};
    int pf,pc;

    if (buscarPrimoMatriz(matriz1)==1)
        printf("HAY ALGUN PRIMO");
    else
        printf("NO HAY PRIMOS");
}

int buscarPrimoMatriz (int matriz1[N][M])
{
    int i,j,x,b,exito;
    exito=0;
    b=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    x=1;
    while (i<N && exito==0)
    {
        j=0;
        while (j<M && exito==0)
        {
            while (exito==0 && x<=matriz1[i][j])
            {
                if (matriz1[i][j]%x==0)
                {
                    b++;
                }
                x++;
            }

            if (b==2)
                exito=1;
            else
            {
                x=1;
                b=0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;

    }
return exito;
}
```

El código no está acabado porque me he quedado bloqueado y no sé si el código que llevo está bien, ya que la función no se ejecuta nunca. Gracias de antemano por toda la ayuda.

Comment: Fijate que la matriz es de 3x3 mientras que `N` vale 2... ese programa no deberia compilar

Comment: En el enunciado se menciona que la función tendrá que devolver 3 valores. Para este caso tendrás que aumentar el número de argumentos para poder devolver el valor de la fila y la columna.

Answer (score 1):

El enunciado implica que la función deberá devolver 3 valores. Dichos valores son:

- Un valor lógico que indique si existe un número primo dentro de la matríz
- La fila en donde dicho elemento existe. En caso de no haber, devolver un -1
- La columna en donde dicho elemento existe. En caso de no haber, devolver un -1

Las funciones en el lenguaje C solo pueden devolver un valor a la función que hace la llamada a través de la instrucción `return`. Es por eso que se tendrá que hacer de otros recursos que ofrece el lenguaje para poder devolver los dos valores restantes. La propuesta que hace esta respuesta a tu pregunta es usar apuntadores para devolver la fila y columna.

El prototipo de la función entonces quedará de la siguiente forma:

```
bool buscarPrimoMatriz (int matriz1[][M], int *, int *);
```

Como segunda mejora a tu programa es el refactorizarlo para usar estructuras de repetición `for`. La estructura quedará de una forma mas legible debido a que son repeticiones definidas a base de un contador.

La tercera mejora propuesta será el crear una nueva función `verificarPrimo()`que checará si un número es primo o no.

El programa quedará entonces de la siguiente forma:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 2
#define M 3
#define EXITO true
#define PRIMO_ENCONTRADO   true
#define NO_PRIMO_ENCONTRADO   false
#define NUMERO_PRIMO    true
#define NO_NUMERO_PRIMO false

bool buscarPrimoMatriz(int [][M], int*, int*);
bool verificarPrimo(int);

int main()
{
    int matriz1[N][M]= {{1,2,1},{3,1,2}};
    int posicionFila;
    int posiciónColumna;

    if (buscarPrimoMatriz(matriz1, &posicionFila, &posiciónColumna) == EXITO)
       printf("HAY ALGUN PRIMO");
    else
        printf("NO HAY PRIMOS");
}

bool buscarPrimoMatriz (int matrizNumeros[N][M], int *p_posicionFila, int *p_posicionColumna)
{
    int i,j;
    bool resultado;

    resultado = NO_PRIMO_ENCONTRADO;
    *p_posicionFila = -1;
    *p_posicionColumna = -1;    

    for(i = 0; (i < N) && (resultado == NO_PRIMO_ENCONTRADO); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; (j < N) && (resultado == NO_PRIMO_ENCONTRADO); j++)
        {
            if(verificarPrimo(matrizNumeros[i][j]) == NUMERO_PRIMO)
            {
                resultado =  PRIMO_ENCONTRADO;
            }
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Ahora, ya teniendo el recorrido de la matriz, procedamos a la función que verificará si un número es primo o no: `verificarPrimo()`. Recordemos la frase de divide y vencerás. Si dividimos el problema en funciones será mas claro el propósito de cada línea del programa:

```
bool verificarPrimo(int numeroPorVerificar)
{
    int i;
    bool resultado = NUMERO_PRIMO;

    for(i = 2; (i < numeroPorVerificar) && (resultado == NUMERO_PRIMO); i++)
    {
        if(numeroPorVerificar % i == 0)
        {
            resultado = NO_NUMERO_PRIMO;
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Notarás que los límites del ciclo van de 2 a uno antes que el `numeroPorVerificar`. Aquí no estoy checando los casos obvios para números primos. El ciclo de hecho se puede optimizar para checar solo la mitad de los casos.

```
for(i = 2; (i <= numeroPorVerificar/2) && (resultado == NUMERO_PRIMO); i++)
```